# OIDC authentication failure logs for ECR

Tags: oidc, ecr

I'm trying to use OIDC with bitbucket pipelines and AWS/ECR. I'm typically getting errors like:

```
An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the DescribeRepositories operation: 
The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I have attempted a basic cloud trail but I don't seem to be picking up ECR OIDC logins.
How do I get access to more detailed authentication logs in AWS for Federated credentials? The logs in the Bitbucket-pipeline for me are too limited for me to search online for...